# What do I better to study to be a competitive writer in here?

Tags: discussion, community-user

I wonder what kind of degree people have in the English Learner’s Forum.

1. BA in English
2. BA in Linguistics
3. BA in Education

I want to be a good writer like James K or Mari Lou-A.

Comment: Would you be studying in an English-speaking environment or not?

Comment: @Lambie I’m studying in an environment far from English. I mean, even not in a Latin, French, German, or Indo-European language speaking environment. :)

Answer (score 8):

I apologize if I’m misunderstanding you, but it seems like you’re asking what kind of degree you need to pursue in order to be as “qualified” as the people who answer questions in the ELL forum (I’m assuming you’re referring to responders, not askers).

The answer is **none of the above**. As long as you have the capacity and knowledge to answer a learner’s question to the best of your ability, I don’t see why a degree would matter. After all, you don’t need a degree in education to be good at explaining things, nor do you need an English degree to have a good grasp of idiomatic grammatical structures. I, for one, have none of those degrees!

Remember, **degrees tend to reflect a person’s interests**, not the other way around. In other words, what a person gets their degree in usually represents their already existing goals, interests, and passions. If you’re passionate about education as a whole, get a degree in it! But this is just a forum, not a university course. It’s a community!

Answer (score 1):

I am not one of those named by the OP on this thread, but I am a moderately frequent responder on ELL. I have no degree of any kind in English, linguistics, nor any related field. My profession is software development, in which communication skills are important, but formal English grammar is not.

I have long been an avid reader, and have been interested in grammar and etymology from a relatively early age, as were my mother and maternal grandmother. But I have more individual experience than formal training in such matters.

I agree with Annabeth Yeung that no particular degree or expression is needed. An ability to explain oneself so that others understand is helpful.